# where is the error in the code of string reverse.c programming?

Tags: c

I want to use pointers to reverse a string and store it to new Array but my code is not working:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
char A[80]="This is the String";
char B[160];
int main(){

  int size=(sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]));
  char *pA;
  char *pB;
  pA=A;
  pB=(B+size);
  puts(A);
  while(*pA!='\o')
  {
     *pB--=*pA++;
  }

  puts(B);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int size=(sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]));` --> `int size=strlen(A);` and include `string.h`

Comment: @CoolGuy `strlen()` returns `size_t`, not `int`. Please use the appropriate type, as `int` is not guaranteed to be large enough to hold a value of type `size_t`.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves `size_t` is indeed the most correct type to use. `int` is however likely able to hold numbers up to 2,14 * 10^9. So unless you somehow manage to pass a string of memory size 2,14 Gb to the program, int will suffice.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of errors:

`sizeof(A)` will evaluate to 80, because that's the size of the array. You need `strlen(A)` instead, and the correct type is `size_t`:

```
size_t size = strlen(A);
```

To use `strlen()`, you need to include `string.h`.

Then, you need to terminate `B`. You never do it. So, start by terminating `B` before entering the loop:

```
*pB-- = '\0';
```

Also, you made a typo in the loop condition. You wrote `'\o'` instead of `'\0'`.

So, putting it all together:

```
int main(void) {
    size_t size = strlen(A);
    char *pA;
    char *pB;
    pA=A;
    pB=(B+size);
    puts(A);

    *pB-- = '\0';
     while(*pA!='\0')
     {
         *pB--=*pA++;
     }

     puts(B);

     return 0;
}
```

Finally, please note that when the loop is over, `pB` will point to a position immediately before the first position of the array `B`. You should try to avoid computing pointers to addresses that are not inside an array or one past its end, because strictly speaking it is against the rules in the standard.

Comment: Note that in the original code, pB pointed one character past the end of the array (should crash). This code gets away with it because it uses strlen() instead of sizeof when calculating size.

Comment: @Lundin Hum, note that the size of `B` is 160. `sizeof()` was applied on `A`, which has length 80. So, `pB = B+size` looks ok to me.

Comment: Alright so it won't crash because out of bounds, but it will write the new string with a strange offset 1 in array B, instead of offset 0. And B[0] will contain garbage. Example: A is `hello\0`, size 6 when calculating the size with sizeof. pB is set to point at B[6] instead of B[5].

Comment: @Lundin Yep, probably not what OP wants. Plus, the original code never terminates `B`, although that is not necessary, since `B` is static, but for ease of readability I chose to make it explicit. And it also makes sure the code will work if someone makes `B` a local variable.

Comment: Anyway, just wanted to point out that your code fixes this bug too, intentionally or not :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all `while(*pA!='\o')` must be `while(*pA!='\0')`

Secondly you have to add a `'\0'` at the end of buffer B

Third the sizeof is not the way to calculate the string length, use strlen instead.

Comment: Also Is this code is efficient for execution  Point of view

Comment: What do you mean? Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

There are several changes I would recommend:

1. The null terminating character is `\0`, you mistyped `0` as `o`.

2. Change the post-increment to pre-increment here:

```
   *(--pB)=*pA++;
```

3. Use `strlen`, not `sizeof` to calculate string length.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char A[80]="This is the String";
char B[160]="\0";
int main(){

int size=strlen(A);   //change 3
char *pA;
char *pB;
pA=A;
pB=(B+size);
puts(A);
while(*pA!='\0')   //change 1
{
   *(--pB)=*pA++;   // change 2
}

puts(B);

return 0;
}
```

[Working code](http://ideone.com/xEo3r6)

Comment: You didn't terminate `B`.

Answer (score 0):

There are three errors. The first one is a typo. Instead of

```
while( *pA! = '\o' )
```

there must be

```
while(*pA! = '\0' )
```

The second one is that instead of

```
int size=(sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]));
```

you have to use the length of the string stored in array A

```
size_t size = strlen( A );
```

And at last instead of

```
*pB--=*pA++;
```

you have to use

```
*--pB=*pA++;
```

Take into account that if the arrays would be declared as local variables of function main (that is if they had automatic storage duration) then you also need to append array B with terminating zero after copying in it array A. You need not do this in your program because objects with static storage duration are zero-initialized.

So the valid program will look like

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char A[80] = "This is the String";
char B[160];

int main( void )
{
    size_t size = strlen( A );

    char *pA = A;
    char *pB = B + size;

    puts( A );

    while( ( *pA != '\0' ) *--pB = *pA++;

    puts( B );

    return 0;
}
```